# Can I play PSP games on my PS Vita?

Tags: ps-vita, psp

I would like to borrow my friends PSP game cartridges but I have a PS Vita.

Are the PSP games compatible with the PS Vita? Will I have to do anything in order to get it to work?

Comment: The PSP doesn't use cartridges at all, it uses UMD, which is a kind of small DVD in a case. The PS Vita uses cartridges.

Comment: http://www.cnet.com/news/psp-games-that-secretly-run-on-the-vita-all-you-need-is-a-ps3/ this may help